# Facebook Canvas Application Firefox Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: facebook, canvas

I have just launched a beta version of my Facebook Canvas Application called Pazooza (http://apps.facebook.com/pazooza), but I am having trouble getting rid of the horizontal and vertical scrollbars in Firefox. In my app settings canvas width is set to 760px and canvas height to fluid.  Does somebody have a canvas html template that they have used that I can try and get to work in my site where firefox doesn't show the horizontal and vertical scrollbars?  My main html table that holds all other content is set to 740px, so I don't see how this voilates the extra width put on by a horizontal scrollbar.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.